# Application interchange profile Interpretation

Tags: apdu, contactless-smartcard, emv, tlv

Im working on Paypass contactless transactions, and I need to send Read Records commands.

I have got the following response to my GET PROCESSING OPTIONS command:

`77 16 82 02 59 80 94 10 08 01 01 00 10 01 01 01 18 01 02 00 20 01 02 00` :

`77 Response Message Template Format 2

```
82 Application Interchange Profile

    5980
94 Application File Locator (AFL)

    08010100100101011801020020010200
```

The second byte of the AIP indicates that the Mchip profile is supported `(10000000)`.

The first byte `(59=1011001)` indicates the capabilities of the card to support specific functions in the application when the PayPass interface is used. My problem is that I should send several Read Record commands depending on the value of each bit of the AIP first byte.

`(AIP=01011001)`

Bit 8=0: RFU
Bit 7=1: Off-line static data authentication supported

Bit 6=1  Off-line dynamic data authentication not supported

Bit 5=1  Card holder verification supported

Bit 4=1  Terminal risk management to be performed

Bit 3=0  Issuer authentication supported

Bit 2=0  RFU

Bit 1=1 Combined DDA – GENERATE AC supported

I need to be sure that the interpretation of this AIP i gave you is correct! Thank in advance .

Answer (score 1):

It looks right according to the spec.

Check out EMV contactless spec v2.5 Book C-2 Annex 1.16 page 472 (The PDF is available at emvco.com) Chapter 6 also describes how READ RECORD should be implemented (6.5 to 6.8)

Answer (score 1):

You would not normally determine which READ RECORD commands to issue dependent on what is in the Application Interchange Profile. If you are following EMV, your READ RECORD commands will be dictated by the content of the Application File Locator.